# Best mysql statement to insert time n calculate difference

Tags: java, mysql, sql, timestamp

I would like to know what is the best statement to get the actual time and then calculate the difference between two times. Should I use datetime or timestamp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datediff() or timediff() to calculate the difference between dates or times respectively.  See the documentation here on how to use them:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

For example:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');

SELECT TIMEDIFF('2000:01:01 00:00:00', '2000:01:01 00:00:00.000001');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what the date and time represent.
[Read here for when to use timestamp vs datetime](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/timestamp-vs-datetime-which-should-i-be-using). Calculation wise I don't think one is better than the other. If you can same your time as a long that might be more efficient for mathematical operations.